# Defined Equation not correctly converting

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to convert the inputted Imperial measurements into Metric, but the conversion is not correct, and I'm not sure why.
For example, a combined total weight Imperial unit input of 50 pounds results in the output being 17.72 kilograms.
Any advice, critics, or code changes are welcome.
This is my code:

```
# Convert the total weight from Imperial, to Metric units
def convertWeight(totalWeight):
  return (totalWeight * 0.45359237)

# Calculate the cost of transport, by multiplying certain weight conditions by their respective cost per kilograms
def getRate(totalWeight):
  if totalWeight <= 2:
      rate = totalWeight * 1.10
  elif totalWeight > 2 and totalWeight <= 6:
      rate = totalWeight * 2.20
  elif totalWeight > 6 and totalWeight <= 10:
      rate = totalWeight * 3.70
  elif totalWeight > 10:
      rate = totalWeight * 4.20
  return rate

# Get the number of boxes
numBoxes = int(input('Please enter the number of boxes: '))
# Get the unit of measurement
unit = input('Please enter the unit of measurement, Imperial or Metric (as I or M): ')
# If the inputted unit of measurement does not equal one of these conditions, ask again for the unit of measurement, until one of these characters are inputted.
while unit not in ['I','M','i','m']:
   unit = input('Please enter the unit of measurement again, Imperial or Metric (as I or M): ')

totalWeight = 0
# For each box, get their respective weight
for x in range(numBoxes):
   weight = float(input('Please enter the weight of the boxes: '))
# Sum up the total weight by adding the inputted weights
   totalWeight = totalWeight + weight
# Does not work, check Parlas answers ; If the inputted unit is Imperial, convert it to Metric
   if unit in ['I', 'i']:
       totalWeight = convertWeight(totalWeight)
   else:
      totalWeight = totalWeight

# Calculate the transport cost, by calling the rate function
transportCost = getRate(totalWeight)
# Output the number of boxes, the total weight, and the transport cost to the user
print('The number of boxes is {0}, the total weight is {1:.2f} kilograms, and the transport cost is ${2:,.2f}.' .format(numBoxes, totalWeight, transportCost))
```

Comment: Do you know that you can use `number1 < variable < number2` rather than `variable > number1 and variable < number2`?

Comment: Can you please explain, using code?

Comment: @zondo: the way he is cascading his `elif`s, `totalWeight > n` is redundant anyway.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Make sure it actually shows the problem (your code didn't do that for me) and it's actually minimal (i.e. if you are having troubles with the unit conversion code strip the user interaction code).

Comment: DW lads, fixed it. I was adding the converted weights, instead of just converting the total.

Comment: @Nick: For example, `elif totalWeight > 2 and totalWeight <= 6:` can be simplified to `elif 2 < totalWeight <= 6:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your Imperial weight conversion,

```
   if unit in ['I', 'i']:
       totalWeight = convertWeight(totalWeight)
```

is inside the get-weights loop,

```
for x in range(numBoxes):
    weight = float(input('Please enter the weight of the boxes: '))
    # Sum up the total weight by adding the inputted weights
    totalWeight = totalWeight + weight
```

So if (for instance) you have 2 boxes each weighing 25 pounds, the metric weight should be `(25 + 25) * 0.4536` but instead you are calculating `((25 * 0.4536) + 25) * 0.4536`.

Make sure the conversion only happens *after* you get all your weights.

Answer (score 0):

I just reduced the indent of:

```
if unit in ['I', 'i']:
    totalWeight = convertWeight(totalWeight)
else:
    totalWeight = totalWeight
```

My previous code was converting each individual weight, then adding it to the total, rather than just converting the total...
Rookie mistake.